# Javascript Dates and Formats

Tags: javascript, date

New to JS. Can someone explain why the 2 dates aren't equal even though it's just the format that's different?

[image]

Comment: The first notation uses ISO format without timezone specification and is interpreted as expressed in UTC timezone , while the second is interpreted as a date/time in the local timezone. It is best practice to not rely on string parsing, except when the string is in ISO format.